# Custom WCF Service for SharePoint 2010

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I read couple of articles about creating custom WCF services for SharePoint 2010 and each suggests creating it under SharePoint project (as oppose to creating a separate WCF Application project or WCF Library). Also, I came across [SharePoint WCF best practices](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8665.sharepoint-2010-best-practices-where-to-publish-a-wcf-service-en-us.aspx).

So my question: is it possible to create a standalone WCF Service and have an option to deploy it inside of SharePoint (let's say I don't want this service to be a part of my wsp)? And what is the best practice?

thanks.

Comment: yes offcourse you use custom wcf service in sharepoint 2010,
Refer this link:http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Calling-a-WCF-Service-using-jQuery-in-SharePoint-the-correct-way.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be part of your wsp file if you are going to deploy it in a SharePoint web app. You can create a stand alone wcf service that can connect to a SharePoint site collection and you can also use the SharePoint Client Object Model to remotely connect to a SharePoint site collection. There are numerous walkthroughs on how to do this.

Here is a good starting point for the Client Object Model http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx